# Looking for a couple of good Blogging applications in Rails or PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, blogs

I would like to have a good blogging application developed in Ruby On Rails, or alternative in PHP (I prefer Rails actually, but PHP could work as well).

I know a couple, as Simplelog, but it threw a couple of errors the first time I tried to run it, and once I fixed them, I didn't like it pretty much.

Comment: Why are you looking for a "couple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails **Mephisto** is widely used blogging engine that has ready-to-use plug-ins and advance feature like built-in caching system for faster loading.

http://www.mephistoblog.com/

If you are looking for some light weight small team oriented, you can easily turn **Radiant CMS** into blog this also have nice and user friendly futures.

http://radiantcms.org/

And my fav is Typo 
It comes with theming & plugins support for easier customization( i like SEO futures )

http://blog.typosphere.org/

I tried and tested all above apps they easy to insatll, configure and short learning curve

Answer (score 3):

WordPress is by far the most popular PHP blogging software, and maybe the most popular period. You can have it up an running in under 5 minutes. It is consider one of the best blogging software out there.

Moveable Type would be the other most popular one, but that is written in Perl with some support for PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). (It's what powers GitHub Pages.) If you're looking for something with a full-on CMS style interface, this isn't it. It's just a static site generator and it's very simple. But, because of that, your blog will be much faster to load (since there's no processing being done, they're just static html files being served) and less likely to be hacked like wordpress, etc.

It also pairs well with [disqus](http://disqus.com/) if you need a commenting system.

Just a thought if you're looking for something a little different.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to choose a blog application. I however was choosing between PHP and Asp.Net. In the end I (reluctantly) went with the ever popular Wordpress. Due to its popularity, you can't beat it for the sheer number of plugins and themes available for it.

Apologies that I know nothing about Ruby blogs, but I'm sure there are none with the same number of themes and plugins as WordPress.